# How to delete a word from an array in swift?

Tags: swift

I have the following variable:

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Apricot", "Banana", "Blueberry", "Cantaloupe", "Cherry","Clementine", "Coconut"]
```

For any of those fruits I have another variable: apple = 1 or 0, appricot = 1 or 0 ...

My question is how to make, for example, the word "Apple" be in the list just if apple == 1? and if apple == 0 my list would be:

```
var fruits = [ "Apricot", "Banana", "Blueberry", "Cantaloupe", "Cherry","Clementine", "Coconut"]
```

Comment: First you should use a Bool instead of an Int. Second it shouldn't be a variable. Just create a dictionary

Comment: what is 'variable : apple = 1'
?

Comment: please post your full code

Comment: You need a dictionary instead of Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **To remove an element from your array you just need to use `fruits.remove(at: [index])`**

So, in your example it would look like this:

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Apricot", "Banana", "Blueberry", "Cantaloupe", "Cherry","Clementine", "Coconut"]
var apple = 0

if apple == 0 {
    fruits.remove(at: 0) //remove 0th index in your array, which is "Apple"
}
```

- **To approach it a safer way, you can use `fruits.filter { $0 != "[fruit name]" }`. This keeps the original array, and creates a new array.**

It would look something like this:

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Apricot", "Banana", "Blueberry", "Cantaloupe", "Cherry","Clementine", "Coconut"]
var fruits2 = fruits
var apple = 0

if apple == 0 {
    fruits2 = fruits.filter { $0 != "Apple" }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest removing from the original array, if the values of apple, banana etc are changed on user input and apple becomes 1 when it was 0 before, the item is removed permanently from the array.

Comment: Added the `filter` function in case OP wants to be explicit on what he wants to remove.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want you **fruits** array to be **Apple** if `apple == 1` or the array of fruits without **Apple**. You can use the code below. If I didn't understand the question and this is not what you want to reach, please post more code and be more explicit.

```
 var fruits : [String] = []

        if apple == 0 {
         fruits = [ "Apricot", "Banana", "Blueberry", "Cantaloupe", "Cherry","Clementine", "Coconut"]
        } else {
        fruits = ["Apple"]
        }
```

## Later edit:

Alright so I understand your question better. You want to build an array of fruits, if the variable for fruit is 1, you want it in array.

To begin with, you must use a `Bool` type of variable instead of `Int`.

You can use 2 arrays, one with `Bool` and your `fruits` variable. Match their indexes, for example `fruitsIncluded[0]` will match for `fruits[0]` which is `"Apple"` in your case. Then create a final array of fruits (`finalArrayOfFruits`) where you have the fruits that are `true`

```
var fruits = [ "Apple", "Apricot", "Banana", "Blueberry", "Cantaloupe", "Cherry","Clementine", "Coconut"]
var fruitsIncluded = [true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false]

var finalArrayOfFruits : [String] = []

for i in 0..<fruits.count {
if fruitsIncluded[i] {
finalArrayOfFruits.append(fruits[i])
}
}
```